# Subscribing to system events in C# with P/Invoke in Mono

Tags: c#, events, mono, pinvoke, systemevent

I have an application in which I need to respond to events such as a user change in the system time (like the *Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.TimeChanged* event), the changing of display settings (*SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanging* and *SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged*) and the resuming from sleep or hibernate (*SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged*. The problem is, in my application, the SystemEvents class is not available. So, I was wondering if there is a P/Invoke / WinAPI way of accomplishing the same thing (which I'm sure there is).

Comment: Yeah, I spent a couple hours Googling, but I didn't really find a concise answer.

Comment: But you should have access to the SystemEvents class, there is really no need for PInvoke. Why can't you use that class?

Comment: My application runs on the Mono framework (an open source implementation of the .NET Framework), and the SystemEvents class is not implemented in Mono.

Comment: You need it for Windows or?

Comment: Yeah, it's gonna run on Windows only.

Comment: The class is a wrapper for a wide range of APIs, which events do you have in mind?

Comment: That would be the _TimeChanged_, _DisplaySettingsChanging_, _DisplaySettingsChanged_ and _PowerModeChanged_ events, as I stated in the question, too.